# git rebase -i をしたときにエディタは開くが、何も表示されない

Tags: git, vim

`git rebase -i` をしたときにVimは開くのですが、何も表示されません。

想定している動作は以下ですが、

`$ git rebase -i <コミット>`

```
====
# エディタが開くので以下のように変更して保存

# (変更前)上から順に古いコミットが並ぶ
pick aa11bbc コミットメッセージ１
pick b2c3c4d コミットメッセージ２
pick 4e56fgh コミットメッセージ３
・・・

# (変更後)対象のコミットをeditに変更
edit aa11bbc コミットメッセージ１
pick b2c3c4d コミットメッセージ２
pick 4e56fgh コミットメッセージ３
・・・
====
```

自分の場合、何も書かれていない状態のVimエディタが開きます。

例えば、そこで正常終了(自分の設定ではTab+e)するコマンドを打つと

```
commit 457dd58fa22f10eeb2794357fbe8c7e1b09cfdeb
Author: Me <me@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Mar 24 09:35:38 2017 +0900

                e
```

git logにはこのように書かれてしまいます。
何か原因が思い浮かぶ方いれば、お力添えをお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim の設定が悪さをしている可能性が高いです。
無設定の Vim で試してみてください。

```
$ GIT_EDITOR='vim -u NONE -i NONE -N' git rebase -i ${commit}
```

これでうまくいくようであれば、Vim に入れている設定やプラグインが悪さをしています。部分的に設定やプラグインを無効にするなどして、徐々に絞り込んで原因を特定すると良いでしょう。

Comment: 回答頂いたものを実行し、表示させることができました。助かりました。

Comment: vimrcを全て消しても直らないのですが、この場合考えられる理由はありますでしょうか。。。

Comment: vimrc を全て消した状態で Vim を起動し、`:scriptnames` コマンドを実行してみてください。読み込まれているスクリプトファイルがあれば、ここに表示されます。これらのスクリプトの中に原因がある可能性が高いです。

Comment: 消してみましたが、変わらず表示されません

Comment: `:scriptnames` コマンドの結果を教えてください。

Comment: `1: ~/.vimrc
  
2: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0456/share/vim/vim80/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 
 3: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0456/share/vim/vim80/plugin/gzip.vim
 
 4: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0456/share/vim/vim80/plugin/logiPat.vim
 
 5: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0456/share/vim/vim80/plugin/manpager.vim
 
 6: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0456/share/vim/vim80/plugin/matchparen.vim
 
 7: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0456/share/vim/vim80/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
  
8: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0456/share/vim/vim80/plugin/rrhelper.vim
`

Comment: `9: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0456/share/vim/vim80/plugin/spellfile.vim
 10: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0456/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 11: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0456/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tohtml.vim
 12: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0456/share/vim/vim80/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 13: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0456/share/vim/vim80/plugin/zipPlugin.vim `
です。

Comment: 余計なものは特に見当たらないので、vimrc が空だとするとおかしいですね。あと考えられるのは可能性は低そうですが、`$VIMINIT` や `$EXINIT` 環境変数が設定されていたり、`$MYVIMRC` 環境変数が設定されていたり、`git config core.editor` におかしな値が設定されている、などでしょうか。

Comment: `$ git config --global core.editor 'vim -c "set fenc=utf-8"'`というコマンドで解決しました。原因は.gitconfigのcore editorに`editor = vim -w`と書かれていたことでした。